# Unable to save KML file using QgsVectorFileWriter

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I am using this code:

```
default_filename = Path.home() / "Documents/test.kml"
outputlayer, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save KML file", str(default_filename), "KML Files (*.kml)")
if not outputlayer: return
outputlayer = Path(outputlayer)
if outputlayer.suffix != '.kml': outputlayer = outputlayer.with_suffix('.kml')
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.includeZ = True
options.fileEncoding = "utf-8"
options.driverName = "KML"
options.overrideGeometryType = QgsWkbTypes.PolygonZ
options.datasourceOptions = ['NameField=target_geometry_label']
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(
                                        layer=self.poly_layer,
                                        fileName=str(outputlayer),
                                        transformContext=QgsCoordinateTransformContext(),
                                        options=options)
```

and the output I get is this:
[image]

There is definitely polygons in the layer:
[image]

And I have tried writeAsVectorFormatV2 as well as the original writeAsVectorFormat which worked for me a few months ago when I was saving shape files. Is it not working now because this is a postgres layer? here is the layer:

```
uri.setDataSource('', 'target_geometry', 'target_geometry_geometry', 'target_geometry.target_geometry_set_id = %s'%(self.poly_set_id,), 'target_geometry_id')
self.poly_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "target_geometry", "postgres")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.poly_layer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by running this before writing:

```
self.poly_layer.selectAll()
clone_layer = processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures", {'INPUT': self.poly_layer, 'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})['OUTPUT']
self.poly_layer.removeSelection()
```

And then I write the clone_layer instead of self.poly_layer

I would still be curious to know why writing the postgres layer doesn't work.